# Proving $(φ(x)\cdot ψ(x)) \cdot ω(x)=φ(x) \cdot (ψ(x)\cdot ω(x))$ where $φ,ψ,ω$ are polynomials on a ring $R[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

If I take $3$ random polynomials $φ,ψ,ω$ on a ring $R[x]$, I'm trying to prove associativity which is very obvious. But I have trouble on the algebra part with the sums. I know that given $2$ polynomials $φ,ψ$ we have $φ*ψ=κ$, where 
$$\begin{align} 
φ &= (a(0),a(1),\dots), \qquad (i=0,1,2, \dots), \\
ψ &= (b(0),b(1),\dots), \qquad (j=0,1,2, \dots), \\
κ &= (d(0),d(1),\dots), \qquad (m=0,1,2, \dots), \\
d(m) &= \sum_{i+j=m} a(i)*b(j). \end{align}$$

Please help if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Did you try a little induction of the sum of the degrees? That can help quite a bit...

$$\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i\sum_{k=0}^mb_kx^k=a_0b_0+x^2\sum_{i=1}^na_ix^{i-1}\sum_{k=1}^mb_kx^{k-1}$$

But then both summands on the right are polynomials the sum of which degrees is less than the original ones'...

Comment: How will the sum of the degrees will be helpfull?I have to prove equality among 2 polynomials their degree must be the same  and their coefficients.

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis, I know how to prove equality between polynomials. Thank you. I'm giving you **a hint** to prove what you want, and you could begin by using the inductive step to write the product of the two sums (polynomials) on the right side...

Comment: Of course you know i didnt mean to be rude.It's just that i didnt "get" it.So you mean i have to write the whole product of the 2 polynomials and the do it a again with a third polinomial and then go backwards ?...that's alot of multiplication